# Better way to deal with nil slice indexes

Tags: go, slice

I have started a project for creating reports by utilizing excel data and the various Go excel libraries (excelize, tealeg's xlsx)

One of the biggest frustrations I have found is working with slices which have some nil indexes depending on the source of data (blank rows in the input data transfer as "nil" slice indexes when I use the xlsx library to pull data)

These nil slice index throw an "index out of range" obviously if I ever try and utilize them in one of my many for loops - which leads me to the painstaking task of ensuring each time I want to work with a slice index that is isn't actually nil by using len() and cap to death()(excerpt of code below to illustrate)

```
    //example code excerpt
    for rowNumber, cellStringSlice := range inputSlice {
        for rowColumn, cellString := range cellStringSlice {
            //loop var declaration
            rowColumnHeading := 2 
            rowNumberInc := rowNumber + 1
            rowNumberDec := rowNumber - 1

            if rowNumber > 0 {
                if len(inputSlice[rowNumber]) != 0 { //len check to stop index out of range issue with slice
                    previousColACellValue = inputSlice[rowNumber][rowColumn]
                    continue
                }

            if len(inputSlice[rowNumber+1]) != 0 { //len check to stop index out of range issue with slice
                        nextColACellValue = inputSlice[rowNumber+1][rowColumn]
                        continue
                    }
                }

            }
```

I should specify that in this 2D slice I am using:

```
inputSlice[rowNumber][rowColumn]
```

the proximal slice (rowNumber) is never nil (there is always a row) however the second distal slice it indexes (rowColumn) Can be nil on some instances - which is why in this scenario my overall loop always enters the second inner loop even when it is iterating though a row with no column data (i.e inputSlice[rowNumber][rowColumn] = nil) and brings a frequent need for me to handle index out of range issues

I can't just remove all the nil indexes and shift everything up, as these are representing "blank rows" in the final excel doc I output these rows to.

So my question is, are there any useful go functions or libraries which take care of nil indexes by swapping all nils for "" in slices and 2d/3d slices of type string? Or is it a task for the programmer to always "sanitise" his slices by removing these nils or check for them each time they ever want to access an element?

I appreciate I could write a for loop myself to swap all these nils for a "", but writing a function to do this each time I work with slices of strings containing/possibly containing nil's would seem a little bizarre to me

Comment: Where do you get `inputSlice` from? Do you have any control on how it's created or it's done in some third party function?

Comment: its made in a library function from the xlsx library - specifically xlsx.FileToSlice(excelFileName) gives you a 3D slice containing all the data from an excel file, the first slice being the sheet number, the second being the rows from that sheet and the third being the columns in those rows. Naturally I chopped this down into a 2D slice for the purposes of the operation in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop is on `inputSlice`, so `inputSlice[rowNumber]` is always valid, and since the inner loop is on that row, it is never zero. Thus the first check is unnecessary. If you have a nil or empty slice for `inputSlice[rowNumber]`, the inner for loop will not even be entered.

The second check is necessary, but wrong:

```
if len(inputSlice[rowNumber+1]) != 0 {
```

If `rowNumber` is the last row, then `inputSlice[rowNumber+1]` is not valid as no such row exists. You have to check:

```
if rowNumber<len(inputSlice) {
...
}
```

Comment: What if `inputSlice[rowNumber]` is nil? Without check, `inputSlice[rowNumber][rowColumn]` will panic.

Comment: if `inputSlice[rowNumber]` is nil, the inner-loop will not even enter, because it Is looping on `inputSlice[rowNumber]`

Comment: Ah, i see. Sorry, my bad

Comment: Hi Burak - thanks for answering. That would make total logical sense! However this isn't what I experience when I run my code - the loop still proceeds through past the "for rowColumn" part even if the row column is a nill index - I am quite sure of this as when I don't put in this check, I find in my debug run through I am getting an index out of range when it runs over a nil index in the inner loop

Comment: Looked further and found out why -  this is because after checking, rowNumber **isn't actually ever nil** - it is the second, outer slice (rowColumn) which can be nil in some instances and causes issues in this case. apologies, I shall fix my question above

Comment: Accessing a nil value in an array will not result in an index out of bounds error. Please update the question and show where you get what error.